# Today Extension and container app

Tags: ios, widget, today-extension

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to update in real time the widget without open the container app. I have a string in my app that I store in NSUserDefaults, if I open the app, this string is changing at every 5 seconds and If at the same time I open the extension the string is changing but if I close the app in the extension nothing happen... I want to know if is possible to achieve this. Thanks!!!

Comment: This is the same question that you asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647239/today-extension-update-in-real-time

Comment: Yes dear Tom is the same question, but the advice you gave me not hellped!!! And I think it is not possible to do......